# JACKSON: How to ignore the POJO name while converting a POJO to JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, marshalling, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am using Jackson 2.10.1 library to convert my Java POJOs to JSON and I am getting the below output, I require the output without the POJO name(MyTestPojo here), I have tried various jackson annotations like @JsonIgnoreProperties but those are mostly for the members present in the POJO and not the POJO class name.

```
{
    "MyTestPojo": [
        {
            "CreatedBy": "user1",
            "Name": "testABC",
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedDate": null,
            "IsActive": true,
            "Value": "testABC1",
            "CreatedDate": "2017-03-13 15:41:54.0",
            "Description": "testABC"
        },
        {
            "CreatedBy": "user2",
            "Name": "testABC",
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedDate": null,
            "IsActive": false,
            "Value": "testABC2",
            "CreatedDate": "2017-03-13 15:41:54.0",
            "Description": "testABC"
        }
    ]
}
```

whereas what I require is -

```
[
        {
            "CreatedBy": "user1",
            "Name": "testABC",
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedDate": null,
            "IsActive": true,
            "Value": "testABC1",
            "CreatedDate": "2019-03-13 15:41:54.0",
            "Description": "testABC"
        },
        {
            "CreatedBy": "user2",
            "Name": "testABC",
            "UpdatedBy": null,
            "UpdatedDate": null,
            "IsActive": false,
            "Value": "testABC2",
            "CreatedDate": "2020-03-10 15:41:54.0",
            "Description": "testABC"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to handle this with Jackson annotations?

The POJOs that I have used are-

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ArrayOfTestPojos")
public class GetResponseVO {

    @JsonProperty("MyTestPojo")
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyTestPojo")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private ArrayList<MyTestPojo> MyTestPojoList;

    public ArrayList<MyTestPojo> getMyTestPojoList() {
        return MyTestPojoList;
    }

    public void setMyTestPojoList(ArrayList<MyTestPojo> MyTestPojoList) {
        this.MyTestPojoList = MyTestPojoList;
    }

// standard getters and setters

}
```

and

````````````
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "MyTestPojo")
public class MyTestPojo {

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("IsActive")
    private int isActive;

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private String value = null;

    @JsonProperty("CreatedBy")
    private String createdBy;

    @JsonProperty("CreatedDate")
    private String createdDate;

    @JsonProperty("UpdatedBy")
    private String updatedBy;

    @JsonProperty("UpdatedDate")
    private String updatedDate;

// standard getters and setters.    
}
```````````
I am also generating the XML out of this so you can ignore the annotations relevant to XML.
````````````

Comment: Please add the relevant POJO's and what you have tried to your question.

Comment: @PieterjanDeconinck added

Comment: Not sure if it is possible with jackson annotations. You can try writing custom deserializer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `JsonValue` annotation for that purpose which basically "use-value of this property instead of serializing the container object". it can be used on `getters` also

> @JsonValue indicates that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means signature must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) is to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance. Usually value will be of a simple scalar type (String or Number), but it can be any serializable type (Collection, Map or Bean).

```
@JsonValue
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MyTestPojo")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private ArrayList<MyTestPojo> MyTestPojoList;
```

But that would wrong practice as it will generate JSON like this, which would not be legal `JSON`.

```
{[{"x":"value"}, ...]}
```

If you want to alter only JSON structure (without affecting xml), you can use `MixIn` for that purpose.

```
public interface JsonMixin {

   @JsonValue
   List<MyTestPojo> getMyTestPojoList();   
}
```

And register it with your object mapper and remove `@JsonValue` from the main Class.

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(GetResponseVO.class, JsonMixin.class);
```

Comment: It did work and I get the JSON I require, but as I mentioned in the question part, I am also converting it to XML (based on the user request it can be JSON or XML) and with @JsonValue the XML code is failing with error "**com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Trying to output second root, <ArrayOfTestPojos>**"

Comment: @StuckProgrammer i have the same requirement as yours , xml and json , 
but the wrapper still shows in json  , did you find any answers ?